# Area of a circle by integration

Tags: integration, trigonometry, complex-numbers, circles

So I've been experimenting with new maths and I wanted to know if what I've done is valid.
To start the equation for a circle is $x^2+y^2=r^2$
so $y^2=r^2-x^2$ and $y=\pm\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$
therefore: $$Area=2\int_{-r}^r\sqrt{r^2-x^2}dx$$
I'll spare you the integration
$$Area = 2\biggl[\frac{\arcsin(x)+x\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}{2}\biggr]_{-r}^r$$
$$Area = \arcsin(r)-\arcsin(-r)+r\sqrt{r^2-r^2}-\biggl(-r\sqrt{r^2-(-r^2)}\biggr)$$
$$Area = 2\arcsin(r)+0+0$$
$$Area = 2\arcsin(r)$$
So far so good (using radians obviously) but it doesn't work for anything bigger than r=1 as arcsin is not defined.
Here is my best go but it doesn't work I don't think.
$$e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$$
$$e^{-i\theta}=\cos\theta-i\sin\theta$$
$$e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta}=2i\sin\theta$$
$$\frac{e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta}}{2i}=\sin\theta$$
$$\frac{ie^{-i\theta}-ie^{i\theta}}{2}=\sin\theta$$
$$\frac{ie^{-i\theta}-ie^{i\theta}}{2}=r$$
$$\frac{1}{ie^{i\theta}}-ie^{i\theta}=2r$$
$$\frac{1-ie^{2i\theta}}{ie^{i\theta}}=2r$$
$$1-ie^{2i\theta}=2rie^{i\theta}$$
$$ie^{2i\theta}+2rie^{i\theta}-1=0$$
$$(ie^{i\theta}+2r)^2-4r^2-1=0$$
$$(ie^{i\theta}+2r)^2=4r^2+1$$
$$ie^{i\theta}+2r=\pm\sqrt{4r^2+1}$$
$$ie^{i\theta}=-2r\pm\sqrt{4r^2+1}$$
$$e^{i\theta}=(2r\mp\sqrt{4r^2+1})i$$
$$e^{i\theta}=(2r\mp\sqrt{4r^2+1})e^{\frac{i\pi}{2}}$$
$$i\theta=\ln(2r\mp\sqrt{4r^2+1})+\frac{i\pi}{2}$$
$$\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}-\ln(2r\mp\sqrt{4r^2+1})i$$
Therefore
as $\arcsin(r)=\theta$ 
$$\arcsin(r)=\frac{\pi}{2}-\ln(2r\mp\sqrt{4r^2+1})i$$
$$Area = \pi-2\ln(2r\mp\sqrt{4r^2+1})i$$
But this doesn't work in the slightest ...
Thank you for reading and I hope someone out there can fix this. It's just a hobby thing I do with lots of research so I did not come up with some of the initial ideas myself but I tried my hardest to try and do as much as I could.

Comment: Is that using this method though, if I made a mistake at the start im going to be so mad

Comment: In "sparing us the integration" you made a mistake right out of the gate.  That you don't get a valid measure of the area for $r>1$ should be a giveaway.

Comment: Okay so originally I did it for $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ because I was practicing integration and so I just replaced my 1 with r ... which in hindsight was really stupid

Comment: Thank you anyway. Waste of some free time but it was fun

Comment: I made a mistake, too.  $A = r^2 \arcsin \frac {x}{r} + x\sqrt {r^2- x^2}|_{-r}^{r}$

Comment: Not a waste of time if you learned something :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your integration is wrong. If you want to do the indefinite integral,
$$ 2\int \sqrt{r^2-x^2} \, dx, $$
you set $x=r\sin{\theta}$, so $dx=r\cos{\theta} \, d\theta $, and the integral becomes
$$ 2r^2\int \cos^2{\theta} \, d\theta = r^2\int (1+\cos{2\theta}) \, d\theta = r^2\theta+\frac{r^2}{2}\sin{2\theta} = r^2\arcsin{\left(\frac{x}{r}\right)} + x\sqrt{r^2-x^2} $$
This is continuous for $-r \leq x \leq r$, so we can use it to evaluate the definite integral,
$$ \int \sqrt{r^2-x^2} \, dx = \left. r^2\arcsin{\left(\frac{x}{r}\right)} + x\sqrt{r^2-x^2} \right|_{-r}^r \\
= r^2\arcsin{1} + 0 - r^2\arcsin{-1} + 0 = 2r^2\arcsin{1} $$
since $\arcsin{y}$ is odd. And of course $\arcsin{1}=\pi/2$, so you get $\pi r^2$.

Comment: Yeah I originally integrated $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ to get $\frac{\arcsin(x)+x\sqrt{1-x^2}}{2}+C$ and then when I wanted to do a general formula I just replaced the 1 with r

Answer (score 1):

$$ Area=2\int_{-r}^r\sqrt{r^2-x^2}dx$$

$$= 2r^2\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\cos ^2 (\theta ) d\theta $$

$$=r^2\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\ ( 1+ \cos 2\theta ) d\theta $$

$$=r^2(\theta + 1/2 \sin 2\theta)|_{-\pi/2}^{\pi /2} = \pi r^2$$